# How to close app from PopupWindow when back button pressed?

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

How to close app from `PopupWindow` when back button pressed?

I have a PopupWindow with an Start Button to start Service. Creation of the PopupWindow looks like this:

PopupWindow showup when Service not start yet. PopupWindow get call from LauncherActivity with NoDisplay via sending custom Broadcast to MainActivity.

So PopupWindow is appear on top MainActivity. Then when press back button PopupWindow close and showing the MainActivity.

What I want is when the back button presses from the PopupWindow does not display the MainActivity but closes the application directly!

I has been try use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  finish();
  System.exit(0);
}
```

But still didnt work.

Any idea how I can solve this problem? And is this possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :-

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
  }
```